# Cannot access the Admin section to perform edits on webpage

Tags: admin, singleton

Each time I try to access the Admin control panel of my site, I get an error message saying

```
There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "_singleton/magestore_themeinstaller_model_observer" already exists
Trace:
#0 /home4/opsshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(192): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home4/opsshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::register('_singleton/mage...', false)
#2 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20646): Mage::getSingleton('magestore_theme...')
#3 /home4/opsshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13464): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(152): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13364): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17629): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17220): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home4/opsshop/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(19712): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home4/opsshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home4/opsshop/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}**
```

I am new to Magento and cannot work out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the singleton comes from a custom theme you installed, you can see this by the name `magestore_themeinstaller_model_observer`. This is not default Magento. You should contact Magestore, where you bought that theme, and ask them for support.